# During the Inner Join between a small and a large table the index is ignored

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, data-warehouse, query-performance

I have two simple tables in Postgresql, the first has **1.7 million** rows

```
CREATE TABLE f_occ(
id_data integer ,
dur integer
);
```

the second table has **365** rows

```
CREATE TABLE d_data(
id_data serial ,
full_data date , 
month SMALLINT ,
);
```

To optimize the join between the two tables I tried to create a hash index on id_data, but this is totally ignored. Why does this happen, how can I optimize the query? This also happens when I insert a condition in the where on the table d_data.

```
CREATE INDEX f_occ_id_data ON public.f_occ USING hash (id_data)
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT d.month, s.dur
FROM d_data d, f_occ s
WHERE d.id_data = s.id_data;

"Hash Join  (cost=10.21..34133.23 rows=1705429 width=6) (actual time=1.479..9158.424 rows=1705429 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (s.id_data = d.id_data)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on f_occ s  (cost=0.00..29594.29 rows=1705429 width=8) (actual time=0.096..2992.577 rows=1705429 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=5.65..5.65 rows=365 width=6) (actual time=1.352..1.353 rows=365 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on d_data d  (cost=0.00..5.65 rows=365 width=6) (actual time=0.030..0.656 rows=365 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.919 ms"
"Execution Time 11727.436 ms"
```

Comment: The join does not reduce the number of rows from `f_occ`, so a Seq Scan on the that table table makes sense (after all, you are retrieving all rows from that table). The index might be used if only a small fraction of the rows from `f_occ` would be returned from the join.

Comment: but if I try to insert a where condition like
d.month = 1 the index continues to be ignored, the index is used only in the case in which I put a condition on full_data like
d.full_data = '2017-02-02'

Comment: Then the where condition does not remove enough rows to make the index useful

Answer (score 0):

If a table is small some query optimizer prefer using a full access to the table in memory avoiding the index access.

Another element is the assumption for main/lead table  in you case using an old implicit join syntax based  on where seems you suggest to query optimizer  the sue of f_occ as main/lead table. Try change the sequence for the table adopting as main table the d_data  and adopt the explicit join syntax based  JOIN and ON clause:

```
SELECT d.month, s.dur
FROM d_data d
INNER JOIN  f_occ s  ON  d.id_data = s.id_data;
```

For better performance you should use  composite index allowing to the query optimizer to resolve all the query info related  to the f_occ table directly by index.

```
 CREATE INDEX f_occ_id_data ON public.f_occ USING hash (id_data, dur)
```

Comment: Changing from an implicit join to an explicit JOIN won't make a difference. And the order of the tables for an inner join also makes no difference.